# How is Apache Ignite page memory related to heap and non-heap?

Tags: java, ignite, apacheignite

I have java application running on ignite cluster.
In ignite logs there are various parameters are logged.

eg., heap, non heap and pagememory.

ignite.log

```
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=82885]
    ^-- Heap [used=661MB, free=89.24%, comm=6144MB]
    ^-- Non heap [used=129MB, free=-1%, comm=139MB]
```

The application has around 6Gb heap configured. Non Heap and pagememory parameters are not configured.
In ignite logs, heap usage in always below designated quota.

In same logs non heap values are logged around 140mb max and they are used around 130mb.

And pagememory values are like around 50k-900k. This values gradually increases. When application is started it is around 60k, after two days it reaches 300k. No impact on application performance.

Is this increase in pagememory really concerning, as there isn't much documentation available relating pagememory to heap, nonheap?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it's concerning rather depends on what you're doing! In Ignite, all data is *stored* off-heap. You'd expect the off-heap size to increase as the amount of data stored increases. The heap is used to *process* the data, so you'd expect it to increase as you stream in data, run SQL queries, etc.

Comment: Thanks. In this case I have not configured off heap to particular size, and my data is also much  larger than what the size of off heap printed in logs. I'm still confused.